# Is it possible to show execution time when using pdb?

Tags: python, pdb

When using pdb to debug Python code, I often wish that commands such as `next`, `return`, and `until` would show the time it takes to run until the next time pdb breaks.
Is it possible to change a setting or write a plugin to make this happen?